# Accept cookies on selmnium openbullet

Tags: cookies, app-config, cracking

I am trying to make selmnium openbullet config But I got a cookies pop that i dont know to pass it.

[This is the cookies pop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnihE.jpg)

I tried to Copy **Agree and Proceed** Xpath and make **Wait for element** block and **Click** block but openbullet cant find it

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaGcO.jpg)